# Get cities as values and names for a custom checkout select field in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, city

In woocommerce checkout I should need to set values of options in select field to be the city name and not a numbers (as shown in the screenshot below).

Here is a sample of my code:

```
 $option_cities = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT name FROM $table_name" );
 $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
 $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = $option_cities;
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using [**`array_combine()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to get the array values copied as keys in a new array:

```
 $cities = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT name FROM $table_name" );

 $option_cities  = array_combine( $cities, $cities );

 $fields['billing']['billing_city']['type'] = 'select';
 $fields['billing']['billing_city']['options'] = $city_options;
```

It should solve your problem…

Comment: thank u very very much .. your answer solved the problem ! it worked :)